# Swift SpriteKit "Extra Arguement "size" in call

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skscene

When trying to transition between a SKScene to another SKScene. For example when its game over I use the code below and get the following error:-

> **Extra Arguement "size" in call**

Below is a sample of my code used when this error occurs.

```
let scene = GameOverScreen(size: self.scene!.size) //<<---- Error throws here
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
view!.scene?.paused = true

self.scene!.view!.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
```

This has never happened before in previous games of mine, and I cant seem to figure out why?

Using XCode 7, swift 2 and SpriteKit

Thanks in advance,

Rachel

Comment: I tested your code and everything's fine. Is `GameOverScreen` a subclass of `SKScene`?

Comment: class GameOverScreen: SKScene {
}

works fine for me too on my other game. and the game over screen is pretty much the same. Both screens are SKScene

Comment: Do you have any other initializers in `GameOverScene`? I'd be interested in seeing your GameOverScene, at least any initializers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing this is happening because you have other initializers defined in `GameOverScene` that you haven't mentioned. Since you do that, you don't automatically inherit all of `SKScene`'s initializers. You probably just have to add the following to `GameOverScene`:

```
override init(size: CGSize) {
    // Set up your properties
    super.init(size: size)

    // Do whatever else you need to
}
```

If you didn't have any initializers defined in `GameOverScene`, you wouldn't be seeing this behavior. I'd suggest doing some further reading on [Automatic Initializer Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID222). The section I've linked to on that page describes the rules for when a class inherits the initializers of a superclass. They are not inherited by default.